# Can Priority Queues have empty elements (like arrays)?

Tags: linked-list, queue, element, priority-queue

Hi I am writing an algorithm in algorithm design language for a mock test, for adding an element to a priority-queue.

Now I plan to do this by using the general method of inserting an element into a regular queue at the back and then sorting it into correct place by comparing it (according to priority value) to the element that is positioned before it in the priority-queue.

This is the algorithm I have so far (only for adding items to the priority-queue):

- *element*- element to be added to the queue.
- *queue[ ]*- priority queue element is being added to.
- *n*- the size of the priority queue.
- *tail*- the last element in the priority queue.

**procedure** AddQ (**IN** element, **INOUT** queue[ ], **IN** n, **INOUT** tail)

```
if tail= n then
    print (“Queue is full”)
else {
    tail← tail+ 1
    queue (tail) ← element
}
```

**end**

What I am not sure of is should I have the section which prints that the Queue is full. Am I right is thinking that priority queues have a pointer in the tail element pointing to null to say that there are not elements left?

If so does this mean that priority-queues cannot have empty space (like a standard array for example)for new elements as the tail in the priority-queue points to null, saying no more elements are in the queue? Or am I taking the wrong approach here?

I am confused as to how this works, if someone could clarify I would be very grateful! Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority queues in java are **dynamic** , they can have a minimum number of elements that needs to be in them however the maximum number of elements you put in them is left up to you.If you want to go through a queue to figure out what the last element is or to figure out where the last element is at any point ,you'll need an **iterator** object that'll help you do just that.